# Android Studio Display Elements of Arraylist on ImageView

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I would like to display images that are stored in an arraylist to an imageview.I am using picasso library to store the links.When i press the button next i want the picture to change to the next image.I am using a for loop but i get only the last element.Here is the code:

```
 ImageView image1;

Button bNext,
ArrayList<String>ll=new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fwtografies);
    image1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
    bNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bNext);
    ll.add("http://i.imgur.com/QoUeA2I.jpg");
    ll.add("http://i.imgur.com/21szRz9.jpg");
   ll.add("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ec/Clip_Poster.jpg");

    bBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent fwtografiesActivityIntent = new Intent(Fwtografies.this,MainActivity.class);
            Fwtografies.this.startActivity(fwtografiesActivityIntent);
        }
    });
    bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for(int i=0;i<ll.size();i++){
                sp(ll.get(i),image1);
            }
        }
    });
    bPrevius.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
    });

    sp("http://i.imgur.com/gijIKJO.jpg",image1);
    //sp("http://i.imgur.com/QoUeA2I.jpg",image2);
    //sp("http://i.imgur.com/21szRz9.jpg",image3);
}

public void sp(String a,ImageView b){
    Picasso
            .with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(a)
            .into(b);
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake is that i used for loop where i should use if statment.
This code works for my case:

```
int i=0;  bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //viewFlipper.showNext();
            if(i<ll.size()){
                sp(ll.get(i),image1);
                i++;
            }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you click on Button "bnext" you are going through your whole for-loop and therefore only the last element of your list gets shown. Try:

```
int i = 0;     
bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              if(i<ll.size()){
                 sp(ll.get(i),image1);
                 i++;
              }
        }
    });
```

Comment: this 1 is doing the job,but i can't understand why ifor loop gets all the  elements instead of 1 by 1

Comment: The loop gets all elements 1 by 1, but it happens so fast, that you can not see it.

Comment: i found my mistake.I should not use for cause i can't stop it to each click.I got to use if in order to manage it